# C# Way to serialize List<string> in settings containing any character (Regex/xml)

Tags: c#, xml, regex, settings

I am looking for a neat/clean way to store a list of strings into a [C# settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx) file.  As far as I can work out, you can't store List objects into these settings, so basically it needs to be converted to a string.  For example, say I have a list of names:

- N*a*m*e*A
- Name;B
- Complex, Weird, Name
- Name"nickname"Person

i.e. I am trying to demonstrate a list of names which can possibly contain **any** character.  Does anyone have any recommendations for a neat format + Regex to read it that can handle any character?  Or possibly an easy way to serialize a `List<string>`?

Currently, I am saving them as a simple command delimited string which works fine so long as you are careful with the names (can't have commas), but is destined to break down the line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can select the type of your setting entry as

```
System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection
```

from the Properties.Settings tab.

This will be translated into your config file as something like

```
 <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <string>string1</string>
  <string>string2</string>
 </ArrayOfString>
```