# How to store ListBox items into the file and retrive them back?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I'm working on storing last used settings and then when program starts retrieve them back. Everything works fine but I just don't know how to deal with ListBox items.

To point out one thing is that I'm already using one delimiter to store my settings. I'm getting quite confused when dealing with this problem.

This is how I store my settings:

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int interval = 0;
    int plusMinus = 0;
    int pause = 0;
    int delay = 0;
    int randomLine = 0;

    if (cbPause.Checked == true) pause = 1;
    if (cbDelay.Checked == true) delay = 1;
    if (cbRandomLine.Checked == true) randomLine = 1;
    interval = int.Parse(nudInterval.Value.ToString());
    plusMinus = int.Parse(nudPlusMinus.Value.ToString());

    lastUsed.Text = 
        interval + splitString + 
        plusMinus + splitString + 
        pause + splitString + 
        delay + splitString + 
        randomLine;

    if (nudPlusMinus.Value == 0)
    {
        tmrInterval.Interval = int.Parse(nudInterval.Value.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        tmrInterval.Interval = random.Next(int.Parse(nudInterval.Value.ToString()) - int.Parse(nudPlusMinus.Value.ToString()), int.Parse(nudInterval.Value.ToString()) + int.Parse(nudPlusMinus.Value.ToString()));
    }

    WhenStarted();

    tmrInterval.Start();
}
```

This is how I retrieve them at the program start up:

```
public AutoTyper()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    tmrInterval.Tick += new EventHandler(Interval);
    tmrDelay.Tick += new EventHandler(Delay);
    tmrSpace.Tick += new EventHandler(Space);

    lbMessage.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(lbMessage_SelectedIndexChanged);
    txtMessage.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtMessage_TextChanged);

    SetInterval();

    if (!lastUsed.EmptyFile())
    {
        string[] allSettings = lastUsed.Text.Split(splitChar, StringSplitOptions.None);
        int settingCount = 0;
        int settingNumber = 0;

        foreach (string setting in allSettings) settingNumber++;

        if (settingNumber == 5)
        {
            foreach (string setting in allSettings)
            {
                settingCount++;

                if (settingCount == 1) nudInterval.Value = int.Parse(setting);
                else if (settingCount == 2) nudPlusMinus.Value = int.Parse(setting);
                else if (settingCount == 3) { if (setting == "1") cbPause.Checked = true; }
                else if (settingCount == 4) { if (setting == "1") cbDelay.Checked = true; }
                else if (settingCount == 5) { if (setting == "1") cbRandomLine.Checked = true; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1700779/c-sharp-way-to-serialize-liststring-in-settings-containing-any-character-rege

Comment: @Lloyd: I'm blank about using XML.

Comment: @HelpNeeder there are other way's maybe but this one is the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just retrieve/set `SelectedIndex` after adding all values (unless that happens at design time already).

But in general, I'd rewrite that settings handling. You should store your settings using keys and values. Otherwise you'll run into tons issue if you ever want to add, remove or change the order of some settings.

Comment: Well, this was simplest solution I could come up with and it does seem to do the job.

Comment: It's perfectly fine, if that's all you have to save. But it's just harder to extend (as you might have to handle different versions, too). If you want, have a look at things like serialisation. Would allow you to simply serialize/deserialize an object containing your values (e.g. a struct or map).

Comment: I have no idea how to start with your idea. Do you mind showing me something I can read about relevant topic?

Comment: MSDN. But other than that, this is the first hit I got on Google, explaining the basics: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-serialize-objects-to-a-file - it's not a lot different from simply dropping yur object into a stream.